# Cocoa: setters in an NSViewController view

Tags: cocoa, setter, nsviewcontroller

I'm using an NSViewController class with a single view in it to display a progress indicator bar and some text fields. I'm trying to use `progressIndicator setMaxValue:`and `theTextField setStringValue:` but neither of these are doing anything.

I've done this before and I've checked and rechecked, it's fairly straightforward, the fact that it's not working makes me think that it has to do with the fact that the class is NSViewController. Which is why I tried

```
Timers *aTimer = [[Timers alloc] init];
[aTimer.timerNameLabel setStringValue:@"name"];
[aTimer.progressIndicator setMaxValue:x];
```

in the app delegate which is an NSObject class, but that didn't work either.

I've tried looking around the NSViewController documentation but I can't find anything that says it can't set those values so I don't know what's happening. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use `-initWithNibName:bundle:` instead of a regular `init` to initialize your custom nib.

**EDIT**: It seemed the problem was due to the view not being queried before getting other objects. By calling `[myController view]` you actually load the nib, which isn't done automatically when you initialize the view controller. So before you can use any element of the view, you need to call `[myController view]`

Comment: @Elbimio Have you checked for the label and progress indicator not to be nil?

Comment: It looks like the label is (null)

Comment: @Elbimio Alright, have you set the class of the File's Owner in your nib file to `Timers‘? Have you referenced the two objects as IBOutlets to your File's Owner?

Comment: @Elbimio Now I'm on my iPod and I can't test it, but I remembered something like me having to fist call `[myController view]` before I could use the view. This would then invoke the actual loading of the view, which the initialization method doesn't do automatically. So try to query the view right after the initialization.